# Proving the fixed value theorem for $f:[a,b] \to [a,b]$

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, fixed-point-theorems

My textbook stated the following corollary from the Weierstrass Intermediate Value Theorem:

> Let $f$ be a continuous mapping of $[0,1]$ into $[0,1]$. Then $\exists z \in [0,1]: f(z)=z$

And the proof they gave for this is quite simple:

If $f(0)=0 \vee f(1)=1$ then this is obviously true so let's see the case where $f(0) > 0$ and $f(1) < 1$.

Let's define $g:[0,1]\to \Bbb R$ such that $g(x)= x - f(x)$. Then $g$ is continuous. We have that $g(0) = - f(0) < 0$ and $g(1) = 1- f(1) > 0$ so $\exists z \in [0,1]: g(z)= 0$ which is the same as saying $z - f(z) = 0 \iff f(z) = 0$.

---

So, now they ask me to prove that:

> If $f$ is a continuous function from $[a,b]$ to itself then there is a fixed point.

I think they want the reader (me in this case) to prove this by adapting the proof that they gave for the case where $[a,b] = [0,1]$ but I was not capable of doing so. What I did was:

We know that $[0,1] \cong [a,b]$, so let $g:[0,1] \to [a,b]$ be an homeomorphism.

Let's define a function $f':[0,1] \to [0,1]$ as $f' = \left(g^{-1} \circ f \circ g\right)(x)$. Because each function is continuous then the composition of functions is also continuous. By the corollary $\exists z \in [0,1]: f'(z) = z$. This means:

$$\left(g^{-1} \circ f \circ g\right)(z) = z$$

as $g$ is bijective we can apply $g$ to both sides and get:

$$f(g(z)) = g(z)$$

So there exists a fixed point for the function $f$.

---

Now, first of all, is my proof correct or am I missing some detail?

Second: How can I prove this by adapting the proof they gave for the corollary?

Comment: Your proof is fine. And IMHO it is better to transfer the result as you did than to regurgitate the proof steps

Comment: IMHO? @HagenvonEitzen

Comment: "In My Humble Opinion". By the way, I agree with Hagen completely here.

Comment: Also: I think that your approach may have been exactly what the question-writer intended for students to do.

Comment: I thought so at first. But the bad thing about this textbook is that it's divided by chapters, and usually if something is in one chapter it is not usually used that much in others. 4. Was homeomorphism and this is 5 - Continuous functions, so that was why I was thinking that Maybe I needed to conclude this using the intermediate value theorem (as this specific part is about that). @JohnHughes

Comment: One doesn’t need to know that they are homeomorphic, or what that word means, though it can help. You just need a way construct a function taking [0,1] To itself, coming from a function taking [a,b] to itself. You can do this by linearly rescaling the input and output (ie a very simple homeo) $\tilde f(z)=(b-a)^{-1} (f((b-a)z+a)-a)$. So you don’t need to have learned about homeos. PS $f’$ is common notation for a derivative so I would avoid it in analysis as a separate variable name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is fine, and in fact shows someting more general: the FPP is a topological property. (FPP= fixed point property, every $f: X \to X$ that is continuous has a fixed point)

The proof from the text *is* easily adaptable (but it gets a bit messy). But it's better IMHO to do it the way you did, and note that this fact doesn't hinge on $[0,1]$ per se but on the "topological type" of $[0,1]$.